# Get same json data to root

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data like in the block below.
Same data are `id`, `ip`, `port`, `name` and `mac_id`.
Difference data are `cam_id`,`dvr_analog_channel` and `cam _name`.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15363,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 33,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 33"
    },
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15364,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 34,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 34"
    },
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15365,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 35,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 35"
    }
]
```

I want to above json data like this to JavaScript.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "serverIp": "1.1.1.1",
        "serverPort": 5000,
        "serverName": "Server",
        "serverMacId": "asdasdaad121",
        "channels": [
            {
                "id": 15274,
                "channelNo": 33,
                "name": "IP Channel 33"
            },
            {
                "id": 12363,
                "channelNo": 34,
                "name": "IP Channel 34"
            },
            {
                "id": 15323,
                "channelNo": 35,
                "name": "IP Channel 35"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to convert this json?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: The second one is invalid. You need a key for defining the grouped properties.

Comment: Reason for downvote. No valid attempts added. Provided output is not standard form.

Comment: It's arranged. nestedJson added to second one.

Comment: That edit is still not valid. Maybe you are trying to make a property whose value is an array that contains objects with the cam properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15363,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 36,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 34"
    },
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15364,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 35,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 35"
    },
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "cam_id": 15365,
        "dvr_analog_channel": 36,
        "cam_name": "IP Channel 36"
    }
]
```

my solution here we go

```
const result = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (accumulator?.length === 0) {
    accumulator[0] = {
      id: current.id,
      ip: current.ip,
      port: current.port,
      name: current.name,
      mac_id: current.mac_id,
      nestedJson: [
        {
          cam_id: current.cam_id,
          dvr_analog_channel: current.dvr_analog_channel,
          cam_name: current.cam_name,
        },
      ],
    };
  } else {
    const index = accumulator.findIndex(
      (item) => item.mac_id === current.mac_id
    );
    if (index !== -1) {
      accumulator[index].nestedJson.push({
        cam_id: current.cam_id,
        dvr_analog_channel: current.dvr_analog_channel,
        cam_name: current.cam_name,
      });
    } else {
        accumulator[accumulator.length] = {
      id: current.id,
      ip: current.ip,
      port: current.port,
      name: current.name,
      mac_id: current.mac_id,
      nestedJson: [
        {
          cam_id: current.cam_id,
          dvr_analog_channel: current.dvr_analog_channel,
          cam_name: current.cam_name,
        },
      ],
    };
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

result will be

```
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 5000,
        "name": "Server",
        "mac_id": "asdasdaad121",
        "nestedJson": [
            {
                "cam_id": 15363,
                "dvr_analog_channel": 36,
                "cam_name": "IP Channel 34"
            },
            {
                "cam_id": 15364,
                "dvr_analog_channel": 35,
                "cam_name": "IP Channel 35"
            },
            {
                "cam_id": 15365,
                "dvr_analog_channel": 36,
                "cam_name": "IP Channel 36"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve the result:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 76,
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    port: 5000,
    name: 'Server',
    mac_id: 'asdasdaad121',
    cam_id: 15363,
    dvr_analog_channel: 36,
    cam_name: 'IP Channel 34',
  },
  {
    id: 76,
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    port: 5000,
    name: 'Server',
    mac_id: 'asdasdaad121',
    cam_id: 15364,
    dvr_analog_channel: 35,
    cam_name: 'IP Channel 35',
  },
  {
    id: 76,
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    port: 5000,
    name: 'Server',
    mac_id: 'asdasdaad121',
    cam_id: 15365,
    dvr_analog_channel: 36,
    cam_name: 'IP Channel 36',
  },
]


const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  const { cam_id, dvr_analog_channel, cam_name, ...rest } = c
  const cameras = { cam_id, dvr_analog_channel, cam_name }
  const exist = a.find(obj => obj.id === c.id)

  if (exist) {
    if (exist.channels) exist.channels.push(cameras)
    else exist.channels = [cameras]
  } else {
    a.push({ ...rest, channels: [cameras] })
  }

  return a
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```